# Как инициализировать двумерный массив в структуре?

Tags: c#, массивы, структуры

```
struct Tenz
    {
        public double[,] a;
        public Tenz(double [,] x)
        {
            a = x;
        }
    }
```

вот так я сделал, но как объявить какой длины двумерный массив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указать размер можно только для fixed-size массива:

```
fixed double a[100];
```

Если нужно указать конкретный размер при инициализации ссылочного массива, то это делается так:

```
a = new double[4, 4];
```

Comment: а где это прописывать? я написал 


     public double[,] a= new double[2,2];

он ругается

Comment: > а где это прописывать?

Там, где вам нужно выполнить инициализацию.

> он ругается

Пусть ругается.

Comment: мне нужно выполнить инициализацию в структуре. выходит ошибка такая: "Тензоры.Form1.Tenz.a": в структуре не может содержаться инициализатор полей экземпляров 

    struct Tenz
        {
            public double[,] a= new double[2,2];
            public Tenz(double [,] x)
            {

                a = x;

            }
        }

Comment: В значимых типах инициализация полей возможна только в конструкторе. Однако всегда будет присутствовать конструктор без параметров, который задаст полю типа массив значение null, поэтому, возможно, имеет смысл использовать ссылочный тип (class) вместо значимого (struct).

Comment: а класс я могу как структуру использовать?

Comment: Можете, вам никто не запрещает.

Comment: А почему не просто

    struct Tenz
    {
        public double[,] a;
        public Tenz(double[,] x)
        {
            a = x;
        }
    }

? Вы ведь всё равно затираете массив.

Comment: я то что мне нужно решил иным путем))мне нужен был четырехмерный массив)я не знал о существовании такого что можно размерность массива увеличивать до 4)вот теперь не надо это.вопрос можно закрыть